# sklearn prepare dataset for game winner prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, classification

I want to predict the result of the match based on the results of previous matches. For each match I have this data: ids of team1 players, ids of team2 players, weapon ids of team1 players and weapon ids of team2 players. For example:

```
{
  "team1_ids": [
    12321323,
    1421242,
    54325235
  ],
  "team2_ids": [
    55432453,
    242462,
    2234444
  ],
  "team1_weapon_ids": [
    1,
    3,
    5
  ],
  "team2_weapon_ids": [
    2,
    4,
    6
  ]
}
```

Same records I have for other matches. Total I have about 30 different player ids and only 6 kinds of weapons that are unique for each player in a match.

Is there any simple way to prepare the dataset for further `sklearn` classification? I was looking into different `sklearn` label preprocessings but haven't find the anwser.

It seems, some sort of `sklearn` OneHotEncoder is suitable, but it does not take into account that switching positions of player ids in a team doesn't matter for game result. For y values I use binary labels: 1 if team1 win and -1 if team2 win.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see - you need to encode only the amount of each weapon type that was used by each team.

Therefore I would describe the match records as 6 features per team (amount of usage of each weapon) and 1 label column.

For example:

```
team1_weapon1 |...| team1_weapon6 | team2_weapon1 |...| team2_weapon6 | Result |
    1          ...         1             0         ...       1           -1
    0          ...         0             1         ...       1            1
```

Where each `team[i]_weapon[j]` holds the amount (or binary flag if its unique per game) of weapons of `j`-type of `i`-team and `Result` is the game outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure, but player ids do also affect game result. And as far as I know, such classifiers as neural networks want the input to be binarized.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use player id as-is, since it will cause overfitting. You should either extract summarized features about the player (such as number of previous wins, number of game played, number of games played together, rate of usage of the same weapon etc..) or try to run some dimensionality reduction techniques as ``PCA``, ``LDA``, ``AutoEncoder`` by using all of the player data.